# How to resolve "Stripe::InvalidRequestError, No such customer 'cus_XYZ....'" error for invoicing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just ran into a weird error I cannot seem to resolve. I am trying to send a one-off invoice to some of my Stripe customers. I have stored their customer id's on the server side, however each time I create a one-off invoice, I get the `"No such customer error".`

I have hard-coded their id's on the server side and Stripe will then say it will bill the supplier (it won't send the email however). When I manually create an invoice in the Stripe Dashboard everything works fine.

```
Stripe::InvoiceItem.create({
   customer: stripe_supplier.to_s,
   amount: 1000,
   currency: 'usd',
   description: 'Order fee from LocalVore!',
})

invoice = Stripe::Invoice.create({
        customer: stripe_supplier.to_s,
        billing: "send_invoice",
        days_until_due: 10,
})

invoice.send_invoice
```

When I hit call this (from a parent function, of course) Stripe will say that the customer does not exist (parameter is stripe_supplier which represents our customer id).

Comment: You should log the output of the stripe_supplier value and check if the customer actually exists. Maybe you are missing something there. You can investigate the create invoice operation here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create